# amsmath: Erroneous nesting of equation structures

Tags: pdftex

[image]
[image]

```
\[|{{e}_{j}}\rangle \langle {{e}_{k}}|=\begin{matrix}
    1  \\
    {\begin{align}
            & \vdots  \\ 
            & j \\ 
            & \vdots  \\ 
            & n \\ 
    \end{align}}  \\
\end{matrix}\left( \begin{matrix}
    0  \\
    {\begin{align}
            & \vdots  \\ 
            & 1 \\ 
            & \vdots  \\ 
            & 0 \\ 
    \end{align}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\begin{matrix}
    \begin{matrix}
        1 & \cdots  & {} & k & {} & \cdots  & n  \\
    \end{matrix}  \\
    (\begin{matrix}
        0 & \cdots  & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0  \\
    \end{matrix})  \\
\end{matrix}\]
```

I made a mistake with this formula, but it does not prevent the PDF from being generated：
Package `amsmath` error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;(amsmath) trying to recover with `aligned'. ^^I\end{align}
[image]

Comment: If that's your desired output, then I don't understand why you have the `align` environment in the first place.

Comment: I use mathtype for conversion, for newbies, I don't know anything about latex formula editing

Answer (score 2):

Since the `align` environment works as a mathematical context while the inner of `matrix` is a text context, then `align` should be revised as `aligned` to work. The mistakes and codes are improved as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[|{{e}_{j}}\rangle \langle {{e}_{k}}|=
\begin{array}{c}
1  \\
\vdots  \\ 
j \\ 
\vdots  \\ 
n
\end{array}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
0  \\
\vdots  \\ 
1 \\ 
\vdots  \\ 
0
\end{array}\right)
\begin{array}{rcccccl}
1&\cdots&&k&&\cdots& n\\
(\,0 & \cdots  & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0\,)
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want `aligned` or more likely `matrix`.

But there are much better ways to do what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\bra}{\langle}{|}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ket}{|}{\rangle}

\begin{document}

\[
\ket{e_{j}}\bra{e_{k}}=
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col,code-for-first-col=\scriptstyle]
  1 & 0 \\
  \vdots & \vdots \\
  j & 1 \\
  \vdots & \vdots \\
  n & 0
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle]
  1 & \cdots & & k & & \cdots & n \\
  0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{pNiceMatrix}
=
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[
  first-col,code-for-first-col=\scriptstyle,
  first-row,code-for-first-row=\scriptstyle,
]
& 1 & \cdots & k & \cdots & n \\
1 \\
\vdots \\
j & & & 1 \\
\vdots \\
n
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]